# Laravel error on GMAIL smtp usage: 'Connection could not be established with host "mailpit:1025"'

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, gmail

I'm trying to send emails through Laravel and Gmail usage, nevertheless, it throws this error:

> Connection could not be established with host "mailpit:1025":
> stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for
> mailpit failed: No such host is known.

I don't understand why it tries to connect to Mailpit instead of Gmail.

My .env file looks like this:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com 
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=est.juan.arango1@unimilitar.edu.co
MAIL_PASSWORD=[google app password]
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

and my routing looks like this:

```
Route::get('/senMail', function () {

    try {
        Mail::to('est.juan.arango1@unimilitar.edu.co’')->send(new Subscribe());
    } catch (Throwable $e) {
        return '<div>FAILED ' . $e . '</div>';
    }
});
```

the subscribe template is a regular `php artisan make:mail Subscribe --markdown=emails.subscribers`

I tried to run `php artisan cache:clear`  and `php artisan config:clear` but error kept being thrown, I also changed port 587 to 465 with no success.

Also tried this config in `config/mail.php` file:

```
        'stream' => [
            'ssl' => [
                'allow_self_signed' => true,
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
            ],
        ],
```

Comment: are you trying to conect to GMAIL smtp server with a user that is not GMAIL?  unimilitar.edu.co

Comment: Try `grep -R mailpit * | egrep -v storage` from your project root to find out where it's been referenced.

Comment: It is a gmail account, its just my College's account, still changed it to `MAIL_USERNAME=jp15911u@gmail.com` with its app password and got the same error.

Comment: @aynber Thank you anyber, I found it thanks to that <3

Comment: Gmail requires to create a project before using their SMTP, did you take a look at  information like this? https://www.makeuseof.com/free-gmail-smtp-server-to-send-emails/

Comment: "Also tried this config in config/mail.php file" Remove those unsafe settings immediately, and do not blindly copy and paste things into your code without understanding what they do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

by @aynber:
"Try grep -R mailpit * | egrep -v storage from your project root to find out where it's been referenced."

Its been a little long time since i had thsi issue, but this helped me find the line of code that was still using other smtp provider. Just replaced it with mine.

Answer (score -1):

To use Gmail as a mail server for sending emails, you can utilize the Gmail SMTP (Simple Mail Transfer Protocol) server. Here are the general steps:

first if you are using windows add this to host file in  path: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
127.0.0.1   mailpit

Enable Less Secure Apps:

Go to your Google Account settings.
Navigate to "Security."
Find the "Less secure app access" section and turn it on. Note that this option makes your account less secure, so use it with caution.
Generate an App Password:

If you have two-factor authentication enabled (which is recommended), you may need to generate an "App Password" for your application.
Go to your Google Account settings, navigate to "Security," and find "App passwords."
Use SMTP Server:

Set up your email-sending script or application to use Gmail's SMTP server.
Here are the SMTP settings:
SMTP Server: smtp.gmail.com
Port: 587
Username: Your full Gmail address (including @gmail.com)
Password: Your Gmail password or the App Password you generated.

Answer (score -1):

**1st Step**

```
php artisan config:clear
```

**2nd Step**

```
Use app password
```

Answer (score -1):

I run this `grep -R mailpit * | egrep -v storage` by Juan Pablo Arango Lizcano
and discovered that cache is using the unconfigured `.env`

[image]

and then I run
`php artisan config:clear` to remove the cached configuration

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

Try this both commands in terminal

php artisan route:clear     // this clear the route cache

php artisan config:cache    // this clear the config cache

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't know why all these negative votes!
This answer actually helped move to the next step when trying to solve the issue I had with mailing.